# Patterns for balancing processing between content scripts and background scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome plugin that changes the content of some pages. Taking a look at a extension that does something similar (https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter). I saw that the plugin uses the backgound script to do the heavy lifting and content script to take care of less intensive tasks and it delegates the hard work (via message passing) to background scripts. Is this a pattern? Should I avoid havy processing tasks on content scripts and create a background script for that?

Comment: It depends on how heavy the processing is. It may be too heavy for one background process (in case you can't use web workers for some reason), or it may depend on data that's too expensive to transfer. There are no patterns, only case by case analysis. Also note, lots of developers simply love to overengineer things just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a pattern but it's kind of common sense. As background scripts runs in a different context, if the extension is doing heavy work and it eventually crashes, then the current page won't be affected.

Also, you'll get the chance to use the devtools profiler and other devtools features to analyze your extension. This is pretty cool since you'll be able to know what's dragging your extension performance if that is the case.

In brief, it's a great idea to move all the heavy processes to background and use content scripts only to deal with DOM manipulation.